# Android ksoap2 parameter issues

Tags: android, web-services, parameters, ksoap2

I am trying to pass a parameter to my service, the code runs but the service never receives the parameters?? The call works, I simply add the variable then get it back, when getting it back I discover the webservice never received it!

Thanks for your help

```
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://NathofGod.com/GetCategoryById";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCategoryById";
    final String NAMESPACE = " http://NathofGod.com/";
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:4021/Service1.asmx";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

 PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi1.setName("name");
        pi1.setValue("the name");
        pi1.setType(String.class);
        pi1.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
        request.addProperty(pi1);

 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       HttpTransportSE conn = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            conn.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about why is not working, but I remember using it with

```
request.addProperty("name", "my_Name");
```

and it worked fine, otherwise you may wanna check the server side...

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                return "Hello Android World";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Why Wont You WOOORK";
            }

          
        }

Answer (score 1):

**This line of code was my issue!**!!

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
```

REMOVE IT

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it following the instructions [on the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#How_to_see_raw_xml_request_and_response_e.g._for_debugging?).

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code a little and put it in a function. I'm not sure if something is different but this code works. Thanks for the responses.

public SoapObject soap() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
     {

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
    request.addProperty("name", "myname"); 
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
    HttpTransportSE conn = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    conn.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
    SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); 
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

final String NAMESPACE = " http://NathofGod.com/";

Change to

```
final String NAMESPACE = "http://NathofGod.com/";
```

Remove the empty space and make then namespace as it is on your request XML. Please note that it is case sensitive as well.