# How to pass object from android to soap web service?

Tags: android, ksoap2

I need to pass an object from android to a soap web service, but I get an error that the driver object is null. How can I pass an object to the soap web service without getting this error?

Here is the object:

```
<soap:Body>
<CreateDriver xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <objDriver>
    <status>int</status>
    <DriverId>int</DriverId>
    <FirstName>string</FirstName>
    <LastName>string</LastName>
    <AccessCode>string</AccessCode>
    <Picture>string</Picture>
    <Signature>string</Signature>
    <Email>string</Email>
    <Phone>string</Phone>
    <Status>int</Status>
    <CreationDate>dateTime</CreationDate>
    <ModificationDate>dateTime</ModificationDate>
    <CreatedUserId>int</CreatedUserId>
    <CreatedUser>
      <status>int</status>
      <UserID>int</UserID>
      <FirstName>string</FirstName>
      <LastName>string</LastName>
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <ConfirmPassword>string</ConfirmPassword>
      <UserMail>string</UserMail>
      <CreationDate>dateTime</CreationDate>
      <ModificationDate>dateTime</ModificationDate>
      <Status>int</Status>
      <CreatedUserId>int</CreatedUserId>
      <ModifiedUserId>int</ModifiedUserId>
    </CreatedUser>
    <ModifiedUserId>int</ModifiedUserId>
    <ModifiedUser>
      <status>int</status>
      <UserID>int</UserID>
      <FirstName>string</FirstName>
      <LastName>string</LastName>
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <ConfirmPassword>string</ConfirmPassword>
      <UserMail>string</UserMail>
      <CreationDate>dateTime</CreationDate>
      <ModificationDate>dateTime</ModificationDate>
      <Status>int</Status>
      <CreatedUserId>int</CreatedUserId>
      <ModifiedUserId>int</ModifiedUserId>
    </ModifiedUser>
  </objDriver>
  <bytArrPicture>base64Binary</bytArrPicture>
  <bytArrSignature>base64Binary</bytArrSignature>
</CreateDriver>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my code:

```
public void postData() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    CreateDriver cDriver = new CreateDriver();
    cDriver.setFirstName("n");
    cDriver.setLastName("n");
    SoapObject objDriver = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    objDriver.addProperty("FirstName", "n");
    objDriver.addProperty("LastName", "n");

    // request.
    // request.addProperty("CreateDriverSimple",request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                                                 SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(objDriver);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this thread, he had similar problem and the solution was provided there [Android ksoap2 parameter issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814164/android-ksoap2-parameter-issues/7814380#7814380)

```
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

            //Use this to add parameters
            //request.addProperty("Parameter","Value");

            //Declare the version of the SOAP request
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            //Needed to make the internet call
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Comment: I always get driver object null

Comment: maybe there is a problem in NAMESPACE or METHOD_NAME. I have some working code on a different pc, if you don't figure it out, I will post it later tonight

Comment: there isn't any problem with namespace or method name i've checked thoroughly

Comment: I added the one that it worked for me, just I remembered that I passed the parameters as properties, I hope it will help you somehow :)